# JQuery Text Replacement on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, replace

I'm trying to create 4 boxes that, upon clicking a button at the bottom of each box, will create an overlay on top of that box. I've never used javascript/jquery before, so my code is a bit basic.

***Question***: I need the text in each button to change to "Less Information" when the overlay is shown, but change back to "More Information" when the overlay is removed (either by clicking that button or opening up one of the other overlays).

***PS***: If you hate my code and want to simplify it (it's very repetitive, I'm not sure how to make it more advanced and cool), please go ahead (explaining what you did would be super helpful as well).

My HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Country Profiles</title>
<link href="Includes/Country_Profiles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="Includes/About_Us.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="Includes/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#button_food").click(function(){
       $("#food_facts").slideToggle(500);
       $("#water_facts").slideUp(500);
       $("#health_facts").slideUp(500);
       $("#care_facts").slideUp(500);
       });
   $("#button_water").click(function(){
       $("#water_facts").slideToggle(500);
       $("#health_facts").slideUp(500);
       $("#food_facts").slideUp(500);
       $("#care_facts").slideUp(500);
       });
   $("#button_health").click(function(){
       $("#health_facts").slideToggle(500);
       $("#water_facts").slideUp(500);
       $("#food_facts").slideUp(500);
       $("#care_facts").slideUp(500);
       });
   $("#button_care").click(function(){
       $("#care_facts").slideToggle(500);
       $("#water_facts").slideUp(500);
       $("#food_facts").slideUp(500);
       $("#health_facts").slideUp(500);
       });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="country_container">
    <div class="h1">Country</div>
    <div class="info">Info Paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec interdum blandit fringilla. Sed sit amet ante eu nisl porta accumsan. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec a consequat ipsum. Morbi sed justo porttitor, rhoncus dolor vel, ultrices odio. Curabitur lobortis vitae nisi dignissim malesuada. Praesent vitae elementum tellus, in pretium nunc. Fusce libero neque, dignissim eget magna et, vulputate ullamcorper urna. Integer a leo sed leo fringilla pulvinar. Sed fringilla mattis mauris quis placerat. Ut rhoncus lectus massa, a sagittis sapien ullamcorper ut. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Mauris sagittis gravida justo, vitae laoreet mi posuere bibendum.</div>
    <div class="pillar_blocks">
        <div class="block" id="food">
            <div class="more_facts" id="food_facts"><h3>Food - More Facts</h3><p><ul><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li></ul></div>
            <h3>Food</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec interdum blandit fringilla. Sed sit amet ante eu nisl porta accumsan. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec a consequat ipsum. Morbi sed justo porttitor, rhoncus dolor vel, ultrices odio. Curabitur lobortis vitae nisi dignissim malesuada.</p>
            <div class="button" id="button_food">More Information</div>
        </div>
        <div class="block" id="water">
            <div class="more_facts" id="water_facts"><h3>Water - More Facts</h3><p><ul><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li></ul></div>
            <h3>Water</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec interdum blandit fringilla. Sed sit amet ante eu nisl porta accumsan. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec a consequat ipsum. Morbi sed justo porttitor, rhoncus dolor vel, ultrices odio. Curabitur lobortis vitae nisi dignissim malesuada.</p>
            <div class="button" id="button_water">More Information</div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="block" id="health">
            <div class="more_facts" id="health_facts"><h3>Health - More Facts</h3><p><ul><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li></ul></div>
            <h3>Health</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec interdum blandit fringilla. Sed sit amet ante eu nisl porta accumsan. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec a consequat ipsum. Morbi sed justo porttitor, rhoncus dolor vel, ultrices odio. Curabitur lobortis vitae nisi dignissim malesuada.</p>
            <div class="button" id="button_health">More Information</div>
        </div>-->
        <div class="block" id="care">
            <div class="more_facts" id="care_facts"><h3>Care - More Facts</h3><p><ul><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li></ul></div>
            <h3>Care</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec interdum blandit fringilla. Sed sit amet ante eu nisl porta accumsan. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec a consequat ipsum. Morbi sed justo porttitor, rhoncus dolor vel, ultrices odio. Curabitur lobortis vitae nisi dignissim malesuada.</p>
            <div class="button" id="button_care">More Information</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

.country_container {
    width: 800px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-family: "FreightSans Pro Black", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.info {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-family: "FreightSans Pro Book", Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.pillar_blocks {
    width: 840px;
    height: 820px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    left: -28px;
}
.block {
    width: 360px;
    height: 360px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 19px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 19px;
}
.block h3 {
    font-family:"FreightSans Pro Black", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
}
.block p {
    font-family:"FreightSans Pro Book", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#food {
    background-color: #EF7314;
}
#water {
    background-color: #02a8c1;
}
#health {
    background-color: #ee3124;
}
#care {
    background-color: #80c342;
}
.more_facts {
    width: 400px;
    height: 372px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#food_facts {
    background-color: #EF7314;
}
#water_facts {
    background-color: #02a8c1;
}
#health_facts {
    background-color: #ee3124;
}
#care_facts {
    background-color: #80c342;
}
.button {
    width: 400px;
    height: 27px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "FreightSans Pro Medium", "Arial Bold", sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-top: 7px;
}
#button_food {
    background-color: #EF7314;
}
#button_food:hover {
    background-color: #D76812;
}
#button_water {
    background-color: #02a8c1;
}
#button_water:hover {
    background-color: #0297AE;
}
#button_health {
    background-color: #ee3124;
}
#button_health:hover {
    background-color: #D62C20;
}
#button_care {
    background-color: #80c342;
}
#button_care:hover {
    background-color: #73B03B;
}
```

Comment: Down voting without commenting - especially to a 1rep is not very constructive. Asker: Create a JSfiddle.net so we don't have to

Comment: Hey, you're better off submitting this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ They can and will look over it for you and improve it :)

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-modal-tutorial/ Found this tutorial to be pretty good. It really goes over the Javascript and technique so you can learn through it and get your task accomplished.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and more properly belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's not about reviewing, though he mentioned it, but what he wants is this line '.. change to "Less Information" when the overlay is shown, but change back to "More Information"..'. It's not super clear what he's asking, that's for sure. Please add further information into your answer what you really want! Code review or is something not working?

Comment: Quick tip: make one button to toggle instead four ones. Each button do the same thing, so, one button with `(this)` to select which to toggle will be much better.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.Next time I'll post elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
        $(this).siblings(".more_facts").slideUp(500);
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
        $(this).text("More Information");
    } else {
        $(".pillar_blocks").find(".selected").siblings(".more_facts").slideUp(500);
        $(".pillar_blocks").find(".selected").text("More Information");            
        $(".pillar_blocks").find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).siblings(".more_facts").slideDown(500);  
        $(this).text("Less Information");
    }
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UehqU/)..